# Range of values of $k$ in floor function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> If the function $f(x)=\lfloor 3.5+k\sin(x)\rfloor$ is
> an even function.Then set of values of $k$ is

Options :

$(a)\ (-0.5,0.5)$

$(b)\ [-0.5,0.5]$

$(c)\ (0,1)$

$(d)\ [-1,1]$

What I try : If function $f(x)$ is even function.

Then $\displaystyle f(-x)=f(x)$

So we have

$\displaystyle \lfloor 3.5+k\sin(x)\rfloor =\lfloor 3.5-k\sin(x)\rfloor $

$\displaystyle \lfloor 0.5+k\sin(x)\rfloor =\lfloor 0.5-k\sin x\rfloor $

(Because $\lfloor x+I\rfloor =\lfloor x\rfloor +I$ )

Now I did not understand how do I solve further, please help me

Comment: Work some examples.  Does $k=100$ work?  What about $k=10^{-10}$?

Answer (score 2):

For $k=\frac 12$, we get
$$f\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)=4\not=3=f\bigg(-\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$$

Therefore, $(b)(c)(d)$ are not correct.

For $-\frac 12\lt k\lt \frac 12$, since we have
$$|k\sin(x)|=|k||\sin(x)|\lt \frac 12\times 1=\frac 12$$
we obtain
$$-\frac 12\lt k\sin(x)\lt\frac 12\qquad\text{and}\qquad -\frac 12\lt -k\sin(x)\lt\frac 12$$
from which we get
$$f(x)=3=f(-x)$$

Therefore, $(a)$ is correct.